# How to access React from outside the App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a React widget which can be loaded on different websites via just one build js file.

I add Event firing from the app which the main app can listen to.

However, I am looking at ways so that the main site can call functions defined in the React app so data can be changed.

I have tried exporting functions from React Components but finding it hard to return local state or update any state values.

```
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="./loginScript.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      document.addEventListener('login', (data) => {
        console.log('Logged in');
        console.log(data);
      });
  </script>
```

So now I want to be able to do it the other way. Something like

```
window.loginApp.updateUserName('Tom');
```

Which will change the app state to Tom etc.

Comment: Have you tried using local storage or session storage?

Comment: I am not sure if want to use storage for this kind of thing. I want to be able to call function inside the React App or dispatch Event for React to listen to

Comment: use `window.postMessage` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to use a React component in another non-react application.

If that's the case, you need to use something like `webpack` or `rollup` to create a build that can be used either with commonJS, amd, or simply by adding it to a  tag

Here is an example of how you can handle this with webpack:

https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#authoring-a-library

Once you build the `LoginApp` library, in the other site you do something like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  ...
  <script src="http://some-location/LoginApp"></script>
  <script>
    window.LoginApp.updateUserName('Tom')
    // ...
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Yep so I created the react app with create-react-app got the build working and able to embed it into a normal webpage.

Now I want to be able to set up communication between the normal web and the react app. Having data pass from React > normal web is fine. But finding it hard for the other way around.

Comment: The thing about create-react-app is that the build it creates wont expose the components to be usable like in the example above, so you need a different type of build for what you want to achieve.

Or maybe I am misunderstanding your needs.